# Are there any general results about the irrationality of $a^{\frac{p}{q}}$?

Tags: reference-request, irrational-numbers

Are there any general results about the irrationality of $a^{\frac{p}{q}}$ for $a\in\mathbb{Z}^+$, $p,q\in\mathbb{Z}$, $q\neq 0$ and $a\neq 1$?

Comment: One knows precisely when $b^{1/q}$ is rational. It isn't difficult to get what you want from this.

Comment: I don't think much can be said, can it? Assuming $p$ and $q$ are relatively prime, $a^{p/q}$ is either irrational, or an integer (if it is rational and $p/q\geq 0$) or the reciprocal of an integer (if it is rational and $p/q<0$). The irrational case occurs precisely when $a$ is not the $|q|^{\textrm{th}}$ power of an integer.

Comment: What do you mean by general? The case $q=2$ is fairly well understood for example. Are you referring to the Gelfond-Schneider Theorem which gives a complete solution for $a,b$ algebraic and $b$ not rational?